# Inserting (Author, Year) citations in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, citing

I've just started to use Latex for my presentations. I'm using beamer but I'm not able to insert citation in the format that I want. I would like to have `(Author, Year)` citations. Like in this image:
[image]

I've my '.bib' file generated from Zotero but I'm not able to find the good combination of Latex packages and commands.
How can I do?

Comment: It depends also on reference style you use: is it apacite ? Could you please provide a Minimal Working Example? Have you included your bib file within the file of your beamer document?

Answer (score 1):

The above sample could be done with

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
%%% THIS ADDS THE COMMA BETWEEN AUTHOR NAME AND YEAR
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

%%% USUALLY YOU'D HAVE YOUR BIB FILE SEPARATE, THIS IS JUST FOR MWE
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{hjelmslev1942langue,
  title={Langue et parole},
  author={Saussure},
  journal={Cahiers Ferdinand de Saussure},
  number={2},
  pages={29--44},
  year={1995}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{A frame title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{Stack Exchange}
\date{2019}

\begin{document}

% \frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame title}
\begin{itemize}
\item Langue et parole \parencite{hjelmslev1942langue}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%\begin{frame}
%\frametitle{Bibliography}
 %\printbibliography
%\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note the `%%%` comments in the MWE